# How to add title / header title to each screen which we navigate through create bottom tab navigator ( react navigation v5)?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

My `BottomNavigation` component:

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

class BottomNavigation extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" backBehavior="initialRoute">
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: 'Start',
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              <Image source={require('../../assets/images/start-tab.png')} />
            ),
            title: 'Welcome',
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Science"
          component={Profile}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              <Image source={require('../../assets/images/science-tab.png')} />
            ),
          }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create StackNavigator to show header title in bottom navigation.

By setting `navigationOptions` inside the component, you apply it to the navigation element that is calling the component.

So in your case, the title you define in `About` applies to the bottom tab, and not to the screen as you would like to.

Rather than setting `navigationOptions` as a static property inside the component, you need to define it directly when creating the stack navigation.

In addition to this, I think you want to nest the stack inside the bottom tab navigation, not the other way around. By doing so, you can have a different title for each screen.

Here is an example:

```js
const AboutStack = createStackNavigator({ About: { screen: About, navigationOptions: { title: 'About Title' } } });
const CreditStack = createStackNavigator({ Credit: { screen: Credit, navigationOptions: { title: 'Credit Title' } } });

const MainNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  About: { screen: AboutStack, navigationOptions: { title: 'About Label' } },
  Credit: { screen: CreditStack, navigationOptions: { title: 'Credit Label' } },
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

Like this, the header title will be "About Title" and the tab label "About Label".